# search and increase the values between the second tilde symbol and the 3rd tilde symbol in each line of a txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, vi

I was wondering is there any way to search and increase the values between the 2nd tilde symbol and the 3rd tilde symbol in each line of a txt file. Maybe `vi` can do this?

For example, i have a `test.txt` file, and 2 lines in it:

```
A~Test1~9463~testA
B~Test2~4825~testB
```

And can be changed to:

```
A~Test1~8352~testA
B~Test2~3714~testB
```

Comment: You mean decrease not increase? And what to do with `0`?

Comment: I am sorry, i should have say decrease in the question. Assuming all the digits are greater than 0, thanks.

Comment: can it be `python` ?

Comment: How about change A~Test1~203000~testA into A~Test1~185000~testA, 203000 field is in hhmmss format and decrease it by 1 hour and 40 minutes. Assuming this field is always greater than 014000, in that case it will not take it back to a previous day.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~";v=1111}{$3-=v; print $3}' file
```

This outputs the modified file to stdout.

```
A~Test1~8352~testA
B~Test2~3714~testB
```

---

To subtract TIME values (hhmmss format), the following works (as per your comment):

input:

```
A~Test1~203000~testA
```

```
awk -v dif="014000" '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS="~"
           difS=toSec(dif) }
    { f3=""
      shoS=toSec($3)-difS
      for( per=3600; per>=1; per/=60 ) {
           ord=int(shoS/per)
           f3=f3 sprintf( "%02s", ord )
           shoS-=(ord*per) } 
      $3=f3
      print }
    function toSec(x) { 
      hh=substr(x, 1, 2)
      mm=substr(x, length(x)-3, 2)
      ss=substr(x, length(x)-1, 2)
      return ss+(mm*60)+(hh*3600) }
    ' file
```

output:

```
A~Test1~185000~testA
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, i appreciate it. What if the value between the 2nd tilde symbol and the 3rd tilde symbol is a time value, and I want to decrease 1 hour and 40 minutes and output it to stdout.

Comment: For example change it from A~Test1~203000~testA into A~Test1~185000~testA  Thank you

Comment: I assume that `203000` is in `hhmmss` format.  What about ithe stiuation when you want to decreace it by more than its own value, which would take it back to a previous day?  .. BTW you should update your *question* with this new information and refer to the edits  here, as a comment.

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes, that 203000 is in hhmmss format, and assuming that the time value is always greater than 014000, in that case it will not take it back to a previous day. I will edit the question in a few. Thanks for the heads up.